# Flip rows with loop over large files in MATLAB

Tags: loops, matlab, text, iteration

I have a huge ascii.txt wind file with the following format.

```
time = 0 hour
2 3 4 5 6 7 
0 9 8 7 6 5
7 6 5 4 3 2
9 8 7 6 5 4
time = 3 hour
2 3 4 5 6 7 
0 9 8 7 6 5
7 6 5 4 3 2
9 8 7 6 5 4
```

The thing is that I need to flip the rows from each block between hours, like this

```
time = 0 hour
9 8 7 6 5 4 
7 6 5 4 3 2
0 9 8 7 6 5
2 3 4 5 6 7 
time = 3 hour
9 8 7 6 5 4 
7 6 5 4 3 2
0 9 8 7 6 5
2 3 4 5 6 7
```

I can do this for one block in MATLAB by

```
    X = readlines('xwind.txt');
    Y = X(2:5);
    Y = flip(Y);
```

But  I couldn’t write the loop for the entire file (4865x1 string).
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try this: `Y = reshape(X, 5, []); Y(2:5, :) = Y(5:-1:2, :); Y = Y(:);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to go between these two row orderings:

```
OriginalRow: [1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 ...]
NewRow:      [1  5  4  3  2  6 10  9  8  7  ...]
```

There is a repetitive pattern here in terms of the relative offset:

```
RowOffset:   [0 +3 +1 -1 -3 0 +3 +1 -1 -3 ...]
```

So a solution to shuffle by this many places could be

```
N = numel(X);                              % Number of rows of text
offst = repmat( [0 +3 +1 -1 -3], 1, N/5 ); % Repeat offset to same size as X
Y = X( (1:N) + offst );                    % Create Y from reordered rows of X
```